# How to access (ping) a VM when not connected to a network?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, virtualbox

I have a mac host with a Virtualbox VM running Linux(ubuntu) and another running Windows.
I have set up a bridged network adapter and a host only network adapter for all my guest VMs.
The host is able to ping the VMs and the VMs are able to ping the host. This works fine when the host is connected to a network. The router at home acts as the DNS so the ping (and other network services)  get routed to the right VM.
**But what do I do when I am not connected to a network?** (I travel a lot) Is there some way (maybe a service) that I can run on the host that will act like a lightweight DNS and route the traffic to the correct VM?

Answer (score 0):

You could look up you vm's local address

```
# ip addr
```

Then edit

```
# vi /etc/hosts "hosts - static table lookup for hostnames "
```

and add your vm local address

You could edit

```
# vi /etc/host.conf
```

order hosts,bind

And change the lookup order.

> "etc/host.conf file. The line order hosts, bind specifies that /etc/hosts takes precedence over the name servers. Changing the line to order bind, hosts configures the system to resolve hostnames and IP addresses using the name servers first. If the IP address cannot be resolved through the name servers, the system then looks for the IP address in the /etc/hosts file. "

Update
You could create a VPN ?

This would allow you to have static ip's and then leave the VPN to deal with the dynamic ip from the router?

> Choose Apple menu > System Preferences,
>
> then click Network. Click Add (+) at the bottom of the network connection services list, then choose VPN from the Interface pop-up menu.
>
> Choose what kind of VPN connection you want to set up from the VPN Type pop-up menu, depending on the network you are connecting to, and give the VPN service a name.
>
> Enter the server address and the account name for the VPN connection.
>       Click Authentication Settings, then enter the user authentication information you were given by the network administrator.
>
> After entering the user authentication information, click OK, then click Connect.

Then point the vm at the new network interface

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natbindip1 "192.168.0.x"
```

You could also run the above in a script to change networks for all the vm's when you're "off line"

Ref [https://Apple support VPN](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14079?locale=en_GB)

Ref [virtualbox.org vboxmanage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-dhcpserver)

Or

This is a little hack.

My router dynamically assigns my ip too. However I force it to give me the IP. I assign the ip by setting it to static on my linux boxes :) This does work in the office. For out of the office I have a backup of my network script so i just drop the network and then replace the file and bring the network up (File location on Fedora/Redhat/Centos /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/)

All the best

Comment: What do you mean by "vm local address"? I have 2 network adapters on the VM, they both have an IP address. Which one do I add to the /etc/hosts?

Comment: Hi AjayI have another idea. Which Vm are you using?

Comment: I have OS X host, 3 ubuntu VMs and one Windows 7 VM. All need to talk to each other over the network. Portforwarding is one option but I don't want to keep track of tens of mappings.

Comment: Hi Ajay. Thanks for the reply. I am human so excuse me if I've got the wrong end of the stick. Which VM provider are you using Eg Parallels, VMware Fusion  VirtualBox Etc?

Comment: Virtualbox, the latest version.